# Strange behaviour on MYSQL querying huge table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to understand a strange performance behaviour happening in a MYSQL data structure that I'm working on:

```
CREATE TABLE metric_values
(
    dmm_id INT    NOT NULL,
    dtt_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    cus_id INT    NOT NULL,
    nod_id INT    NOT NULL,
    dca_id INT    NULL,
    value  DOUBLE NOT NULL
)
    ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE INDEX metric_values_dmm_id_index
    ON metric_values (dmm_id);

CREATE INDEX metric_values_dtt_index
    ON metric_values (dtt_id);

CREATE INDEX metric_values_cus_id_index
    ON metric_values (cus_id);

CREATE INDEX metric_values_nod_id_index
    ON metric_values (nod_id);

CREATE INDEX metric_values_dca_id_index
    ON metric_values (dca_id);

CREATE TABLE dim_metric
(
    dmm_id   INT AUTO_INCREMENT
        PRIMARY KEY,
    met_id   INT              NOT NULL,
    name     VARCHAR(45)      NOT NULL,
    instance VARCHAR(45)      NULL,
    active   BIT DEFAULT b'0' NOT NULL
)
    ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE INDEX dim_metric_dmm_id_met_id_index
    ON dim_metric (dmm_id, met_id);

CREATE INDEX dim_metric_met_id_index
    ON dim_metric (met_id);

CONTEXT:
Some context, I'm trying to understand some strange performance behaviour happening in a data structure that I'm working on:

CREATE TABLE metric_values
(
    dmm_id INT    NOT NULL,
    dtt_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    cus_id INT    NOT NULL,
    nod_id INT    NOT NULL,
    dca_id INT    NULL,
    value  DOUBLE NOT NULL
)
    ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE INDEX metric_values_dmm_id_index
    ON metric_values (dmm_id);

CREATE INDEX metric_values_dtt_index
    ON metric_values (dtt_id);

CREATE INDEX metric_values_cus_id_index
    ON metric_values (cus_id);

CREATE INDEX metric_values_nod_id_index
    ON metric_values (nod_id);

CREATE INDEX metric_values_dca_id_index
    ON metric_values (dca_id);

CREATE TABLE dim_metric
(
    dmm_id   INT AUTO_INCREMENT
        PRIMARY KEY,
    met_id   INT              NOT NULL,
    name     VARCHAR(45)      NOT NULL,
    instance VARCHAR(45)      NULL,
    active   BIT DEFAULT b'0' NOT NULL
)
    ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE INDEX dim_metric_dmm_id_met_id_index
    ON dim_metric (dmm_id, met_id);

CREATE INDEX dim_metric_met_id_index
    ON dim_metric (met_id);
```

CONTEXT:
Metric_values have something close to 100 milion rows and table dim_metric has 1024 rows. 
I'm doing a simple JOIN between this 2 tables and I'm having huge performance issues. Trying to figure out what the problem is I stumbled in this strange behaviour.

I can't execute the JOIN using the column met_id as a filter. I left it running for 10 minutes and lost the connection to the database due to timeout before I got any results back;

Running a explain on the query I can see that the indexes are being used correctly (I assume) and only 1052 rows are being scanned from metric_values.

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT
    count(0)
FROM metric_values v
    INNER JOIN dim_metric m ON m.dmm_id = v.dmm_id
WHERE 1=1
    AND m.met_id = 1;

1   SIMPLE  m   ref PRIMARY,dim_metric_met_id_index,dim_metric_dmm_id_met_id_index  dim_metric_met_id_index 4   const               1       Using index
1   SIMPLE  v   ref metric_values_dmm_id_index  metric_values_dmm_id_index                                  4   oi_fact.m.dmm_id    1052    Using index
```

Doing a simple change to the query to use a sub select instead of a JOIN I can get the results after ~45 seconds.

Running a explain on the modified query I can see that the index is not the primary resource being used to fetch the data and that almost 20 million rows were scaned to bring me the result.

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT
    count(0)
FROM metric_values v
WHERE 1=1
    AND v.dmm_id = (SELECT m.dmm_id FROM dim_metric m WHERE m.met_id = 1);

1   PRIMARY v   ref metrics_values_dmm_id_index metrics_values_dmm_id_index 4   const   19589800    Using where; Using index
2   SUBQUERY    m   ref dim_metric_met_id_index dim_metric_met_id_index 4       const   1           Using index
```

Can someone explain to me what is happening? Did I misunderstood what the EXPLAIN is telling me? Can I do some changes to the data model to improve the query performance?

Comment: For the first query the MySQL optimizer should have choosen 'dim_metric_dmm_id_met_id_index' instead off 'dim_metric_met_id_index'.. try to use a index hint ( https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-hints.html )  `USE INDEX (dim_metric_dmm_id_met_id_index)`

Comment: @RaymondNijland using a that specific index did not improve the performance. I'll read some more about  index hints to see if I can find something that help me. Thank you :)